# How to set up windows 1.0 with ms-dos while keeping the ms-dos cd in the drive

Tags: ms-dos

I am trying to setup Windows 1.0 with MS-DOS running on a Acer Travelmate C110. I have the windows disks, but because I need to keep the dos cd in, I can't install it. Could anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: get a second CD drive might be an option.

Comment: Nope. Second CD Drive would not work. When I tried it, it said "Cannot read drive A:"

Comment: Can you make a CD that contains DOS and all of the contents of the Windows install disks?